# Standard experimental latch and barrier use ptrdiff_t

Tags: c++, concurrency, std

I was looking at the [C++ experimental extensions for concurrency](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/concurrency) and noticed the new synchronization classes `latch`, `barrier`, and `flex_barrier`. They all implement a standard [barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)), either single-use or reusable.

The current documentation states the following signature for their constructors:

```
explicit latch( ptrdiff_t value );
explicit barrier( std::ptrdiff_t num_threads );
explicit flex_barrier( std::ptrdiff_t num_threads );
```

With the following explanation for the `value` or `num_threads` parameter:

> **value**  -  the initial value of the internal counter; must be
>   non-negative
>
> **num_threads**  -  the number of participating threads for
>   the barrier; must be non-negative
>
> **num_threads**  -  the number of
>   participating threads for the flex_barrier; must be non-negative

---

All three constructors accept a parameter of type [`std::ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t), which is a signed integer type. The documentation then explicitly states that the value must be non-negative.

**My question:** what is the rationale for choosing the `std::ptrdiff_t` type as parameter type instead of an unsigned integer type such as [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t). It seems to me that using an unsigned integer type is safer as the constructor can then never be called with an invalid parameter value.

I know that the current definition is *experimental* and inclined to change, but still, the current parameter type was explicitly chosen to be a signed integer type. So there must be some kind of thought behind it, no?

Comment: Indeed, [`boost::latch` uses `std::size_t`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.latches.latch).

Comment: `std::experimental::latch` comes from the proposal [N4392](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4392.pdf) and its authors don't justify their choice for `std::ptrdiff_t`. Maybe we should ask them?

Comment: @YSC Yes, maybe we should ask them. How would you go about this, simply send the authors an email?

Comment: Is the case with unsigned number relevant? I.e. can you have so many threads that you need size_t? I don't think so - and I would thus assume that someone though it better to detect ridiculous values (leading to negative numbers) than to work to support it.

Comment: @HansOlsson The maximum value of `std::ptrdiff_t` is still ridiculously large on modern systems ([more than nine quintillion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9,223,372,036,854,775,807)). Why not simply use `unsigned short` as the type then? It just struck me as odd that they chose a signed type and then had to explicitly document the fact that it had to be non-negative; while using an unsigned type already conveys this kind of information.

Comment: `unsigned short` would be a bit weird. The "use `int` unless there's a good reason not to" rule seems to apply here as well.

Comment: Having an unsigned parameter doesn't stop you from passing a negative value. For example `std::size_t(-1)` is well defined by the standard.

Comment: @MSalters The documentation seems to state the good reason: the value **must** be non-negative. Would they insist on using a signed integer type solely to let implementations throw/assert/... when a potential programming error was detected?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: Not _solely_, but it's a good reason.

Comment: Not only the signed integer is kind of odd, but I find particularly disturbing that they choose **`std::ptrdiff_t`**  whose semantic is to represent pointer difference. What kind of logical link could exist between a pointer difference and a task countdown?

Comment: And yes, I would send them an email.

Comment: There's a push in the standard for using unsigned types only for bit flags and bitwise operations. For math, signed types at least give you a reliable way to debug overflow (since it's UB, an implementation is allowed to give you debug info), unlike unsigned overflow, which is unfortunately well defined and cannot be reliably marked as an error. A count integer seems more prone to be used with math than with bitwise operations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This change was made after discussions at the C++ WG21 meeting in Cologne, in February 2015. I wasn't present, but I incorporated the WG's feedback into the document. AFAIK the concern about having an unsigned value was the a negative signed number might accidentally get cast to an unsigned value. As far as using `short` goes, we wanted to ensure that these concepts were usable in applications written for GPUs where there are potentially very large numbers of subtasks.

Comment: And what about `std::ptrdiff_t` specifically instead of any other signed integer whith less specific semantics?

Comment: The feedback from the Cologne meeting was that either `signed long long` or `ptrdiff_t` would be appropriate types. We chose `ptrdiff_t`. I don't know if that was the ideal solution, but we have heard no further feedback from subsequent meetings that this was wrong.

Comment: In my experience I am using a barrier with something like `vector<thread>`. If we aren't going to use `vector<thread>::size_type` then `vector<thread>::difference_type` seems like a logical choice. Of course, we don't want to restrict barrier usage to the types a vector uses, but the principle generalizes from `size_t` -> `ptrdiff_t`. That's my guess as to what the committee was thinking, anyway.

Comment: "the concern about having an unsigned value was the a negative signed number might accidentally get cast to an unsigned value" Where exactly would this cast take place?