# In C++20, why is std::ptrdiff_t the type of the "expected" constructor parameter to std::latch and std::barrier?

Tags: c++, c++20

Seems like it should be simply *std::size_t*, or perhaps even just *unsigned*.  It's a thread count.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857190/standard-experimental-latch-and-barrier-use-ptrdiff-t